# The 2nd card is red - intuitive understanding of probability

Tags: probability

I have trouble understanding *intuitively* this problem (taken from the book by Blitzstein and Hwang):

A standard deck is shuffled and 2 cards are dealt.

Event $B$ - the 2nd card is red.

It turns out that $P(B)=0.5$ and *algebraicly* I understand why it is so (that's why I omit the calculation here).

Here's the quote from the book **I struggle to understand**: "There are 26 favorable possibilities for the *second* [italicized by the authors of the book] card, and for each of those the first card can be any other card."

How can we say that there are 26 favorable possibilities for the second card? Suppose we know nothing about the first card. If I wanted to find $P(B)$, I would apply the LOTP and considered two events: the first card is red and the first card is black. Which means that we can say that there are 26 favorable possibilities for the second card **only if** the first card is black.

What does the book mean?

Comment: is there any given reason as to why there is an event B but not an event A?

Comment: @Cursed1701 Yes, event A - the first card is a heart. I got the title of the question wrong (( The problem deals with computing $P(A|B)$ and $P(B|A)$ and I seem to understand everything but the phrase that I asked about in the question, that's why I didn't copy the entire problem.

Comment: In this context (calculating $P(B)$) I see no reason to even mind about the first card. There are just exactly $26$ red cards that can turn out to be the second card with equal probability. Yes, the first card will not be the second card, but that is also true for the cards that are not dealt at all.

Comment: @drhab >>I see no reason to even mind about the first card
The reason is because B is the second card and we do not replace the first card after we have drawn it.

Comment: @alekscooper So what? You might as well touch a card blindly and whisper: "you are the first card" and then place one of the other cards. The probability that the placed card is red will not be affected by that.

Comment: P(B|A) doesn't make sense, as if A happens, it happens before B

Comment: @Cursed1701 Sure it makes sense. There is no essential difference between placing 2 cards one by one or simultaniously followed by giving them the labels 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to intuitively accept that the first card of a shuffled deck has $0.5$ chance to be red, regardless of any worry about what the second card is.  Consider shuffling a deck then swapping the first and second cards.  Doesn't the chance that the second card is red have to be $0.5$ if we don't worry about the first card?  You are worried that if we know the first card is red it decreases the probability that the second card is red, which is true.  If we know the first card is black it raises the probability that the second card is red.  The calculation, which you accept, shows these balance out nicely.

Comment: Cool explanation, thank you! I wonder why they don't write books in that way...

Comment: Another way to say the same thing is to ask yourself: Which of the 52 cards is more or less likely to end up as the second card? Answer: none, all are equally likely to end up as the second card. So, 26/52.